# Away3D with Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

I have an Away3D 4.0 application with UI made in old flash display API, which can be only partly hardware accelerated.

On PC works fine, but the frame rate of UI on mobile devices is too low, hence I am porting it to Starling.

So I tried using both Away3D and Starling, but they don't work together (it compiles but there are run-time errors). What do I have to change? Specifically or generally for maybe another 2D library such as ND2D. Are there libraries that support this out of the box?

Edit: First I add an Away3D content and there are no errors. When initialising Starling, the error is in `Starling.as` (a library class) on line 249. I also tried [this](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/away3d-compatibility?replies=3#post-1282) as someone suggested, but didn't make any difference (also information is 3 months old and libraries are being updated).

Edit 2: The error was caused by having a different `enableDepthAndStencil` value as is in Away3D, which is hardcoded in Sparling as false, because it doesn't really need it. Well, after "fixing" this there are no runtime errors: Away 3D content displays, but then I add Starling and the canvas becomes black. I guess I will have to dive into the Away3D source.

Comment: Just telling you have errors will not solve your problem. please update your question and add details about the runtime error codes and when/how it happens. Also any lines of code are welcome.

Comment: What is the actual error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by following instructions in this [comment](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/away3d-compatibility?replies=3#post-4767) and the one afterwards (additionally only had to change `enableDepthAndStencil` to `true` in `Starling.as` in `updateViewPort()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can view the source of the starling library on their github repository.
Here is a link to the Starling.as file>
https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/src/starling/core/Starling.as

the Starling method that is throwing an error is this:

```
        private function updateViewPort():void
        {
            if (mContext)
                mContext.configureBackBuffer(mViewPort.width, mViewPort.height, mAntiAliasing, false);

            mStage3D.x = mViewPort.x;
            mStage3D.y = mViewPort.y;
        }
```

From the look of that you should be able to remove this code for mobile, since your use will not be able to resize the viewport. 
To do this, download the library from the github repository, instead of using the swc onthe starling site. 
https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework
Then you can customize your starling build for compatibility with Away3D.